# How does X chromosome monosomy occur

Tags: development, sex, sex-chromosome

I want to understand how Turner syndrome - monosomy X - occurs at the molecular level. The [NIH mentions](https://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/condition/turner-syndrome#genes) that there are cases of both complete monosomy and of mosaicism.

I’m particularly interested in the monosomy case, as this really confuses me. How does a fertilized egg end up with only one sex chromosome (an X, in this case)? Is an empty egg fertilized by an X-bearing sperm? Is an X-bearing egg fertilized by an empty sperm?

The case of the mosaicism is easier to imagine - say through X chromosome nondisjunction at a very early point in some cells of the embryo. NB: unsure this is actually how mosaic monosomy X happens.

I haven't found a source that doesn't begin from the point at which monosomy has already occurred.

How do things get to that point? Where and how is a sex chromosome lost, such that a human can develop with only the one?

Thanks so much for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, it seems that Turner syndrome is due to fertilization by a sperm cell lacking a sex chromosome. I wouldn't describe such a cell as "empty": it still has the other 22 chromosomes, but in meiosis the sex chromosomes failed to segregate appropriately.

Monroy et al 2002 note that of 10 people with complete monosomy X, 9 had their single chromosome from the mother.

Monroy, N., López, M., Cervantes, A., García‐Cruz, D., Zafra, G., Canún, S., ... & Kofman‐Alfaro, S. (2002). Microsatellite analysis in Turner syndrome: parental origin of X chromosomes and possible mechanism of formation of abnormal chromosomes. American journal of medical genetics, 107(3), 181-189.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't found that reference earlier. Definitely helps me to understand it better.